# Publish to azure app service plan, file not found

Tags: c#, .net, azure

i am using azure service, and i use the right click publish to my windows azure. When i run my project in my visual studio it is fine, however after i publish to azure, all those files cannot be point correctly.

this is my fontawesome css

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

result :

[image]

i run in my local is fine, but not in azure.

Comment: Are you sure Azure is configured to serve .eot files by default? Perhaps you need to [do something](https://gist.github.com/gothandy/382dfc2c1bb0d3841c33) to have it serve them?

Comment: The folders needs to be shared so remote connections (from azure) can get access.  Where do you want the files/folder located so remote connections can be made?

Comment: @mason this is default fontawesome.css, i didnt change anything, i just download and use only

Comment: @jdweng what do u mean

Comment: @ryan1555 So? Why do you think being their default CSS changes anything that I said in my original comment?

Comment: @mason but the local work without changing anything

Comment: The https url is a network driver.  You may have access to the file on the local PC, but when you run from the azure you may not have access to the file.

Comment: @ryan1555 So? It doesn't matter if it's working locally. That doesn't invalidate what I pointed out in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by remove

```
<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />
```

in my webconfig.live